# Reading and printing characters from a user defined text file

Tags: c++, file, printing

I am trying to work out how I can print character by character the contents of a user-defined text file. I believe I have got the retrieval of the file correct but I am unsure how I can print each character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ELEMENT 300
#define LENGTH 20
void main(char str[ELEMENT][LENGTH])
{
FILE *infile;

char textfile[1000];
char read_char;
int endoff;
int poswithin = 0;
int wordnum= 0;

printf("What is the name of your text file?: ");
scanf("%s", &textfile);
infile=fopen(textfile,"r");    

if (infile == NULL) {
 printf("Unable to open the file."); 
}
else
{
endoff=fscanf(infile,"%c",&read_char);
while(endoff!=EOF);
{
```

This is where I believe I'm stuck. The first character is read into the variable read_char but then it doesn't seem to print anything?

```
if(read_char>=65&&read_char<=90 || read_char<=65)
{
    str[wordnum][poswithin]=read_char;
    printf("%c", read_char);
    poswithin++;
}
else
{
 str[wordnum][poswithin]=(char)"\n";
 poswithin=0; wordnum++;
}
endoff=fscanf(infile, "%s", &read_char);
 }
}
fclose(infile);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in the format specifier to your second call to `fscanf`

```
endoff=fscanf(infile, "%s", &read_char);
```

should be

```
endoff=fscanf(infile, "%c", &read_char);
```

Also,

```
str[wordnum][poswithin]=(char)"\n";
```

shouldn't be casting a string literal to `char` and probably should be adding a NULL terminator rather than a newline:

```
str[wordnum][poswithin]='\0';
```

Finally, you shouldn't try to declare `str` as an argument to `main`.

```
char str[ELEMENT][LENGTH];
int main() // or int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: Thank you for your corrections however I'm still unsure as to how I print the character I'm reading? Thanks again.

Comment: `printf("%c", read_char);` is correct.  Note that console output may be line buffered so may not appear on your screen until you print a newline `\n` or explicitly flush using `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: It still doesn't print anything onto the console and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fscanf` with `%c` format specifier is overkill for reading a single character from a file.

Try `fgetc` to read one character.  The function avoids the overhead of parsing a format specifier string and variable number of arguments.

A more efficient method is to allocate a buffer or array and read "chunks" of chars from a file, using `fread`.  You can then scan the buffer or array.  This has less function call overhead than many calls to read single bytes.  Efficient buffer sizes are multiples of 512 to conform with disk drive sector sizes.